# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to read a dataContext class like this

```
var users = new List<User>();
var roles = new int[] { 1, 2 };
// here I need to get users who's role is in role (1, 2), hence above line
// and also I need to get user who's isValid field true, please note that isValid is SQL 'bit' field and is nullable
//This is what I am doing
foreach (var user in dataContext.Users
                                .Where(u => roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value)
                                            && u.isValid ?? false == true)) // here '&&' part I'm struggling and getting above error
{
    users.Add(new User()
    {
         // Users Added in collection
    });
}
```

So the question is in where clause I need to get user's who are in role(1,2) && isValid == true, if isValid is 'null' make it false.
Thanks

Comment: You have to remove possibility of a null on either side of the operand, whether you do it by wrapping it in parenthesis or some other method--> .Where(u => roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value) && u.isValid == true) should also work.

Answer (score 38):

You have to wrap it in parentheses:

```
roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value) && (u.isValid ?? false)
```

> bit of confused with (u.isValid ?? false), does this not mean that if
>   u.isValid == null then make it false and look for users where
>   u.isValid is false, this is not what I want.

No, it just means that `nulls` are treated as `false` and that all users are taken which `isValid` is neither `null` nor `false`. It works because the `??`-operator converts the `Nullable<bool>` to a `bool`, so you can use it with `&&`. I don't like it, i prefer explicit code that i understand later:

```
roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value) && u.isValid.HasValue && u.isValid.Value
```

or simpler by using the `==`-operator with the `bool?`:

```
roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value) && u.isValid == true
```

Comment: But lose the `== true`

Comment: Thanks Tim. This means filter if u.isValid == true and if u.isValid is null filter u.isValid == false. Is that correct?

Comment: If this is correct then I don't want this behaviour, I want to return only if isValid == true. Since isValid is nullable, I wanted to make it false to avoid error and return only records where isValid is true.

Comment: bit of confused with (u.isValid ?? false), does this not mean that if u.isValid == null then make it false and look for users where u.isValid is false, this is not what I want.

Answer (score 8):

Given `bool` will default to `false` anyway you could use [GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value) && u.isValid.GetValueOrDefault()
```

*Note - `GetValueOrDefault` does not appear to be supported by EF - [see ticket](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/112)*

Comment: This is particularly nice, because `GetValueOrDefault()` is a bare field read with no extra logic.

Comment: `GetValueOrDefault()` is not translated into SQL by EntityFramework

Comment: @AlexG that was the only doubt in my mind - can you confirm that this is definitely the case?

Comment: [Here's the issue ticket](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/112)

Comment: @AlexG thanks, however, the question itself is more related to the compiler error rather than the runtime one that would be thrown by EF (although, ultimately this will be the case if the OP uses this code). I will leave the answer but update just to point out that the support does still appear to be lacking for EF (although funnily enough I think this *is* supported by L2S).

Answer (score 2):

You can try  like this.

```
 foreach (var user in dataContext.Users
          .Where(u => roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value) 
             && (u.isValid ?? false))) // note the bracket around (u.isValid ?? false)
```

Or

```
foreach (var user in dataContext.Users
       .Where(u => roles.Contains(u.RoleID.Value) 
        && (u.isValid.HasValue && u.isValid))) //you can use HasValue to check for null
```

Comment: Thanks @sudhAnsu63, but i don't want to filter where u.isValid == null. I want to get records where u.isValid == true and if u.isValid is null, (to avoid compile error, convert this to null to false)

Comment: but return only  records where u.isValid == true

Comment: I have updated my answer(2nd One).  1stOne was already working as expected.

Comment: Thanks, what does this mean in your 1st answer (u.isValid ?? false), does this not mean that if u.isValid == null then make it false and look for users where u.isValid is false, this is not what I want

Comment: null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Comment: @sky: No, it doesn't mean look for users where `u.isValid` is false.  Just as `if (u.IsValid)` looks for users where `u.IsValid` is true, `if (u.IsValid ?? false)` means "look for users where `u.IsValid` is true (and treat null the same as false)"  That's all the `??` does, it provides an instruction to treat null the same as some other value.  It doesn't invert the overall meaning of a filter condition.