# How to rectify the error Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, mvvm

This is my c# code.I'm getting error in this particular line as **Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'bool'**

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() && viewModel.OpenFileCommand.CanExecute(openFileDialog.FileName))
                {
                    viewModel.OpenFileCommand.Execute(openFileDialog.FileName);
                }
```

Please help me to rectify this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426415/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-bool-and-bool)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Window.ShowDialog Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.showdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns `Nullable<Boolean>` A Nullable value of type Boolean that
> specifies whether the activity was accepted (true) or canceled
> (false). The return value is the value of the DialogResult property
> before a window closes.

The problem is the result from `ShowDialog` is *nullable*.

However, you can rectify this by just using the more verbose `== true`, the compiler then  understands you want to explicitly know it's true, and not null or false. Don't ask me why it doesn't like the shorthand version (I'd have to dig through the specs).

Either way, here is your solution:

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true && viewModel....)
```

Comment: @TheGeneral By design a conditional statement only knows the states 'true' and 'false'. Null is actually not a state. It's just a reference that points to no memory. And it just makes no sense to return a reference as a result of a conditional expression. It's a specification introduced to avoid side effects. Let the result of 'ShowDialog()' be null. If the compiler would auto-convert it to false, so that 'if (ShowDialog())' will fail, than the inversion would be critical since 'if (!ShowDialog())' would pass although the returned value is null. It's just specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() ?? false && viewModel.OpenFileCommand.CanExecute(openFileDialog.FileName))
```